# What's the best practice to transfer object with REST from spring boot to angular

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-boot, client-side

Considering an application using:

- Spring Boot on server side ( with hibernate, a DAO pattern and an Oracle db )
- AngularJS on client side
- REST API to communicate ( Spring REST )

What's the most common approach to transfert data? On my previous project, I used DTOs ( with dozer ), but it's hundred additional classes, waste of development time, so I decided to look for a good alternative.

I heard about Jackson?

Create JSON manually?

Make my entity serializable and send them directly?

**Update 2018**

2 years after, I m still using DTO class serialized into json with jackson in all my project, using spring data is not the point here, returning an Entity which is a DB object is not a good practice, you can use @JsonIgnore on some property of your entities but it s not really flexible. You can use the mapper that you want or handmade, MapStruct which is use in the great JHipster project seems a good one.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) with [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/). I use it with angular and it's super easy to expose your business model as Restful Endpoints. You can use Hibernate as a JPA provider. And with Spring Boot you can easily create a project that puts all these together, so you don't have to do anything. It can save you a lot of time.

The process is this:

1. You create the Entity (Model)
2. You create a JpaRepository

End there you have it. The Restful endpoint is generated.

In the front end i use [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).
Also in many cases you can avoid DTO's and use [excerpts and projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts).

Read this guide [Accessing JPA Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/).

Comment: Do you use Thymeleaf and BootStrap? I want to combine them with AngularJS, is this possible and necessary ?

Comment: 2 years after, I m still using DTO class serialized with jackson in all my project, using spring data is not the point here, returning an Entity which is a DB object is not a good practice, you can use @JsonIgnore on some property of your entities but it s not really flexible.